# Performance measurement in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

i want to find the best way to compare two frameworks in android development

i am trying to compare two frameworks in android development. so i created the same application with two different frameworks. i want to compare them by their performance of cpu usage, memory usage, battery usage and start time performances.

i know there is a profiler in android studio and it shows us nice graphs. however i need time series data and average consumption of resources so i can make a scientific comparison.

what is the best way to gather this data and compare them later on?